# Jest Mock Function?

Tags: unit-testing, email, jestjs

Just started using jest and the documentation doesn't seem to be too clear on mocking.

I have a module with the below code. If I want to test the send mail function, but not send an actual email out via mailgun what do I need to do here? I THINK in my test file I need to use the mock behaviour but can't work out how to specifically stop the mail going out, whilst also being able to check the right routes are followed e.g. invalid email address, error thrown, etc. Do I need to break this function down further?

```
const Mailgun = require('machinepack-mailgun');
const Emailaddresses = require('machinepack-emailaddresses');
const config = require('../Config');


// Function to send an email
const sendEmail = function (toaddress, toname, sub, msg, cb) {
// Validate the email address is correct and if so send an email. Otherwise log the error and exit.
  Emailaddresses.validate({
    string: toaddress,
  }).exec({
    error(err) {
      return cb(err, null);
    },
    invalid() {
      return cb(new Error('Email address is not valid.'), null);
    },
    success() {
      Mailgun.sendPlaintextEmail({
        apiKey: config.sender.apiKey,
        domain: config.sender.domain,
        toEmail: toaddress,
        toName: toname,
        subject: sub,
        message: msg,
        fromEmail: config.sender.fromEmail,
        fromName: config.sender.fromName,
      }).exec({
        error(err) {
          return cb(err, null);
        },
        success() {
          return cb(null, 'Email Sent.');
        },
      });
    },
  });
};

module.exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock out `Mailgun` with your own implementation which:

```
const Mailgun = require('machinepack-mailgun');
jest.mock('machinepack-mailgun', () = > ({
  sendPlaintextEmail: jest.fn()
}))
it('sends mail and fail', () = > {
  // no add the way `sendPlaintextEmail` should react.
  // in this case return `exec` which always run the `error` part
  Mailgun.sendPlaintextEmail.mockImplementation(() = > ({
    exec: (arg) = > {
      arg.error('someError')
    }
  }))
  const cb = jest.fn()
  sendEmail ('toaddress', 'toname', 'sub', 'msg', cb) 
  expect(Mailgun.sendPlaintextEmail).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)
  expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)
})
```

In the above example we mock the mailgun module so that `sendPlaintextEmail` is a spy. Then we import the module into our test so we can set the mock implementation of the spy in every test. In the example we set the behaviour, so that it returns the `exec` method, which then is called by your code with the `error`/`success` object. The mock then just call the `error` part. After that you can first test that `Mailgun.sendPlaintextEmail` was called with the correct parameters, then you can test that `cb` was called with `"someError"` and `null`.

In another test you can just set the behaviour of `exec` so it will call the `success` method.

Comment: Thanks I'll review this tonight and mark if no further questions.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Seem to be hitting errors


    error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ["chris@gmail.com", "chris", "subject", "message"]
But it was not called. 

https://pastebin.com/rhxtjkLc

Comment: Could you check that success function of the email validation was called by adding a `console.log(Mailgun.sendPlaintextEmail)`. What does it print?

Comment: Also the `hasBeenCalledWith` should be expect the something like this: `{
        apiKey: config.sender.apiKey,
        domain: config.sender.domain,
        toEmail: toaddress,
        toName: toname,
        subject: sub,
        message: msg,
        fromEmail: config.sender.fromEmail,
        fromName: config.sender.fromName,
      }` and not an array.

Comment: It appears I've got this working. I wish I could tell you why! https://pastebin.com/Mn6yvMiR What is the best way for me to mock out the invalid and error routes in mailgun? Do I just add in the other methods in my mockImplementation?

Comment: Still not sure why my suggested solution not work as it is mostly the same. Anyway, to mock out the other cases, you have to move `Mailgun.sendPlaintextEmail.mockImplementation` inside each of your test for any of the cases.

Comment: Ahh, could it be that the mail validation is async?